# Adding class to fixed element, when he is touching footer

Tags: jquery

i have small problem with this one. I want to hide element x when it touch footer, it works (it completely invisible when touches footer) but somehow when im scrolling it adds every second pixel class "hidden" and then removes it. In effect its flashing when scrolling above footer. How can i fix it?

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(".x").offset().top + $(this).outerHeight() > $('.footer-home').offset().top) {
        $(".x").addClass('hidden');
    } else {
        $(".x").removeClass('hidden');
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you share me the demo fiddle?

Comment: Due you have multiple `x` elements?

Comment: Yes im using x element like this 
<img class="x hidden-sm hidden-xs" src="x.png"/>
<img class="x visible-sm" src="x-tablet.png"/>

Comment: use == instead of >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, fix your JS:

```
if ($('.x').offset().top + $('.x').outerHeight() > $('.footer-home').offset().top) { ... } else { ... }
```

You have to check outerHeight of your fixed element, not this (= window).

And your flashing problem - if you hide element by display: none CSS, it will have height 0px for jQuery, so use visibility: hidden; instead.

Check this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v4xoqta0/)

Answer (score 0):

As you are using multiple elements, You need to check the `offset()` of each element individually and toggle the `hidden` class as per condition.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var windowOuterHeight = $(this).outerHeight();
    var footerOffSetTop = $('.footer-home').offset().top;

    //Iterate x elements
    $(".x").each(function(){

        //Cache variables
        var self = $(this);

        //add/remove class based on state
        self.toggleClass('hidden', (self.offset().top + windowOuterHeight) >= footerOffSetTop);
    });
});
```

Comment: Well it works same as mine code. Maybe problem is somewhere else. Anyway thanks for answer